# mySQL unexpected syntax error with "DECIMAL"

Tags: mysql

This is my 5th day learning SQL on mySQL.

I don't understand why the system tells me the following is an error.

My code is:

```
CREATE TABLE elements(
Name VARCHAR(20),
Symbol VARCHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
AtomicNumber TINYINT, 
AtomicMass DEC(4,2)     -- ending doesn't need ,  similar to SAS
);

INSERT INTO elements
VALUES ('Actinium','Ac',89,227);
-- here we want to modify the field type of the existing table because Aluminum has decimal #'s in mass

ALTER TABLE elements
MODIFY AtomicMass DECIMAL(9,3);  
-- Q:   I do not understand this why this is an syntax error.
```

System Message: "Syntax error: unexpected 'DECIMAL(decimal)'"
It runs and changes the field constraint but the error message is still there.

Additional Question(utterly noob question,please tolerate me): How do you put 'space' in a name of a column? Like now I'm using "AtomicNumber" but I really want "Atomic Number."

Thanks! :)

Comment: Actually, you don't really want "Atomic Number" as a column name in a table; in a query you might, but it is generally a poor practice to do so in tables. If you insisted though, you surround them with "backticks" (the other thing on the ~ key), or quotes (if you have ANSI quotes enabled).

Comment: Also, while it is tempting to be succinct and omit the field list from `INSERT` statements, it is generally not a good practice. In a multi-dev environment, or even for a solo dev wanting to change things later, not specifying the fields in the query means rearranging them in the table later will break all such queries (or let them succeed silently with inappropriate data).

Comment: What should I do if want to input info into my table then? I learned all this from youtube tutorials. Can you also suggest a source for learning SQL?

Comment: specify the fields before VALUES like: `INSERT INTO elements (\`Name\`, \`Symbol\`, \`AtomicNumber\`, \`AtomicMass\`) VALUES ('Actinium','Ac',89,227);`

Comment: What @Devon said. I wasn't saying don't use `INSERT`, just that it is much better "form" to specify fields. (Even if not for stability/reliability, it means you won't have to constantly look back and forth between table definition and query to make sure you matched the order.)

Answer (score 0):

Consult https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html.

You are missing `COLUMN`.

```
ALTER TABLE elements
MODIFY COLUMN `AtomicMass` DECIMAL(9,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the MySQL data type is `DECIMAL`, not `DEC`. So your original table definition statement should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE elements(
  Name VARCHAR(20),
  Symbol VARCHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
  AtomicNumber TINYINT, 
  AtomicMass DECIMAL(4,2)     -- ending doesn't need ,  similar to SAS
);
```

Your modification should look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE elements
    CHANGE COLUMN AtomicMass AtomicMass DECIMAL(10,2)
```

But, you should consider using `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` rather than `DECIMAL` for values like atomic weight.  Two decimal places of precision isn't very representative of the actual scientific truth.

Finally if you want to wrap your column names in backticks like this

```
 `Atomic Mass`
```

everywhere you use them, you can put spaces in column names. But this will drive you crazy when you're writing code, I suspect.